# PHP Export all user-defined variables to file, import if file exists?

Tags: php, variables, crash-dumps

Is it possible to (say, when the PHP script crashes or something) dump all user-defined variables to a file, and then the next time the script runs, import the file and re-set (perhaps from a user-defined list) the variables before it runs?

I'm thinking about writing an entire function for this where it exports in XML, but I'd like it to be able to do it with the output from say, `print_r($array);` where $array has most of the data.

I realize this would fail for variables that are set say, after the script does calculations. Which means we'd have to tell PHP to start from the line it left off at before it crashed. (What other options do I have for running PHP scripts that process 500,000 items and can take 30 hours to run, if the server may/not successfully finish?)

Comment: This would be really hard (/ impossible) to do with instances. Best thing you could do is simply keep track of the items "processed" and pick up where you left by initializing everything again.

Comment: @PeeHaa - If nobody has any answers, I might take the time to attempt this in my own function, which I'd gladly share with everyone. It SHOULD be included with PHP as a default function `core_dump('./dump.bin');` if it crashes, and then `dump_import('./dump.bin', $select);` if it exists, where $select is/are the variables you'd like to import. (That would be included it the beginning of the script, be ignored if file doesn't exist. Alternatively could be used to set specific variables from an array like `$select = array('$var1','$var2',[...]);`

Comment: Have fun I would say and don't go insane ;) This may get you started: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php, http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php, http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @PeeHaa - Thanks, was looking into using a `foreach` with that and `var_dump()`; but the importing is the hard part :) ... /me grabs some coffee.

Comment: Exporting and reimporting a variable dump is no big deal. But reconstructing the Zend engine state (stack etc.) to allow and resume with the previous function/method scope is no small feat.

Comment: @mario - You're referring to "single variables" and not "all user-defined variables" correct?

Comment: From userland you can only see all variables from the local scope, not upper ones (besides top-level `$GLOBALS` of course). Then a simple `file_put_contents("dump.bin", serialize(get_defined_vars()))` and importing them with `extract(unserialize(file_get_contents("dump.bin")));` is likewise trivial.

Comment: @mario - That was essentially the idea. I'll post an answer if I get any working code samples for you. It's a very interesting idea though, in my opinion. Do you think converting it to JSON is a better idea?